# Importing methods from file into a class

Tags: python, oop, function, twisted, irc

I am making an IRC bot with Twisted and I have run into a problem. I want to import functions from a seperate file into my main class (the one that inherits irc.IRCClient) so they can be used as methods. I have thought of two possible solutions, but they both seem a bit newbish and they both have problems.

Solution 1: Put the functions in a class in a separate file, import it into my main file and make my main class inherit the class. The problem with this solution is that I will end up inheriting quite a few classes and I have to modify my main class each time I make a new module for the bot.

Solution 2: Put the functions in a separate file, import it into my main file and assign each of the imported functions to a variable. This is annoying because I would have to set a variable in my main class for each of the methods I want the class to import from somewhere else.

#### Example:

importthis.py

```
class a():
    def somemethod(self):
        print "blah"
```

main.py

```
import importthis
class mainClass(irc.IRCClient):
    thisisnowamethod = importthis.a()
```

As you can see, both methods (no pun intended) require a lot of stupid work to maintain. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class mainClass(irc.IRCClient):

    from othermodule import a, b, c
    # othermodule.a, b, and c are now methods of mainClass

    from anothermodule import *
    # everything in anothermodule is now in mainClass

    # if there are name conflicts, last import wins!
```

This works because `import` simply imports symbols to a namespace and doesn't much care what kind of namespace it is. Module, class, function -- it's all copacetic to `import`.

Of course, the functions in `othermodule` must be written to accept `self` as their first argument since they will become instance methods of `mainClass` instances. (You could maybe decorate them using @classmethod or @staticmethod, but I haven't tried that.)

This is a nice pattern for "mix-ins" where you don't necessarily want to use multiple inheritance and the headaches that can cause.

Comment: from blah import * seems to work completely, but it says "SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level" when I run it. Is this something I should be worried about?

Comment: Didn't realize it did that (only tested the `import a, b, c` form). It's a warning, so you can ignore it, but if it works, I guess that means it's subject to change in a later Python version. It's generally better to explicitly list the symbols you want anyway.

Comment: Alright. It's a little extra work, but if it's better to do it this way I guess I'll do that. :)

Comment: The advantage of doing it that way is you can look at the class definition and see what's actually in the class. Whereas if you just `import *` then you have to go look at the other module. Also, if you add something to the other module it may clobber something you already defined in the class.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question that needs to be answered for each of these imported methods is, does it act on the state of the object?  The answer seems to be no -- they don't know about your main class, and therefore should not be methods on the main class.  And I don't think there's an IS-A relationship between your main class and those that it would inherit from.

But is your problem that you want callers to have access to these methods?  A good solution is to just make these methods available as a module that can be imported.